# Manually changing a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

It's my first time using Rails, and I would like to know if it's ok to manually change a migration file that was created with the CLI. I used the CLI to create a `<date>_create_posts.rb` file, but it's empty:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

I wanna add the properties, but not sure if it's ok to manually change it

Comment: It's ok, just follow the guide https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table

Comment: You would usually run `rails g model Post` to create a table and a model instead of a single migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the migration is generated after running generator command line but not yet persists to the database, you can add more properties confidently.

If the migration is the most recent, and you have already run `rails db:migrate`, you can first try `rake db:rollback` to rollback that migration, and then edit it.